# CardView and other views not showing in android studio layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

CardView and other views not showing in the android studio layout editor.I am providing my Gradle , layout, and layout editor view details. please help

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="380dp"
android:layout_margin="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: gradle]

[image: gradle info]

[image: layout editor preview]

Comment: Did you tried to synce files with gradle and refreshing the layout ? And always don't post codes as images

Comment: ok.i tried,but not working

Comment: are you able to click and go inside the definition of cardview from your xml file?

Comment: HI I got solution. I changed <android. support. V7.widget. cardview to <androidx. support. v7.widget. cardview. Its working now

Answer (score 1):

its because you are using android support in androidx,

remove these support implementation in your app gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28:0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

change your cardview tag to be **androidx.cardview.widget.Cardview**, also you seems **forget to close your cardview tag** in your post

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="awdawdawd"
                android:textColor="#666"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```